# Assigning variables which contain variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have three files named `/opt/Process1.txt`, `/opt/Process2.txt`, and `/opt/Process3.txt`. I would like to assign the contents of each file to a variable respectively. I have tried:

```sh
Num=1
while [ $Num -le 3 ]
 do
  Pass${Num}=`cat /opt/Process${Num}`
  #There is some other stuff but the above is the issue
  Num=`expr $num + 1`
 done
```

It looks like the system is trying to output the content when executed

If I try a static number it is ok I.e

```
Pass1=`cat /opt/Process1`
Pass2=`cat /opt/Process2`
Pass3=`cat /opt/Process3`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sh` or `bash`? In `bash` you could use an array for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry Thomas it is sh

Comment: do you have to use `sh`? Join the late 1980's and use a better shell environment! ;-). If not, you want `eval Var\${num}="stuff here"`. `eval` is considered evil, so be very careful where you use it. Good luck to all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using 3 separate lines here. Not everything needs to be generalized.

Comment: If, by any chance, the input files only contain one line of text, you can use `read`: `IFS= read -r "Pass$Num" < /opt/Process$Num`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `Num=$((Num + 1))` should work as well, unless you are *really* using Bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shell tries to run `Pass1=blablabla` as an executable, which does not exist (`command not found`).

You can work around this using `declare`:

```sh
declare "Pass${Num}=`cat /opt/Process${Num}`"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure how to use the declare, or if I was supposed to replace my line with the one you published, if it was the later I just got an error declare not found

Comment: So no answer to this problem for the .bin/sh, I have looked and tried but no joy, Still think you clever guys and girls out there have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code corrected and your code made to work

```
for Num in `seq 1 3`
 do eval Pass${Num}="$(cat /tmp/Process${Num})"
done
echo $Pass1 $Pass2 $Pass3
```

```
Num=1
while [ $Num -le 3 ]
 do
  eval Pass${Num}=`cat /opt/Process${Num}`
  #There is some other stuff but the above is the issue
  Num=`expr $num + 1`
 done
```

Using the answer provided by Thomas

```
for Num in `seq 1 3`
 do declare Pass${Num}="$(cat /tmp/Process${Num})"
done
echo $Pass1 $Pass2 $Pass3
```

```
Num=1
while [ $Num -le 3 ]
 do
  declare Pass${Num}=`cat /opt/Process${Num}`
  #There is some other stuff but the above is the issue
  Num=`expr $num + 1`
 done
```

Here I run into the same issue

> If you really are only incrementing up by one from 1 to 3 you could also do
>
> ```
> for num in `seq 1 3`
> do
>  Pass${Num}=`cat /opt/Process${Num}`
>  #There is some other stuff but the above is the issue
> done
> ```

Comment: Did you try your code? Did it run without any errors? If it ran without errors, please edit your Q to show the output. (I didn't down-vote, and the person that did should have left you some feedback about why). Welcome to S.O. (sorry!) and Good luck!

Comment: You're totally right @shellter, I didn't clear the $Pass[1-3] out when I ran it with my version so it looked like it worked correctly.

Comment: I just saw you responded with my same findings @shellter, Should I just delete my post?

Comment: I appreciate your effort to improve your answer! You need to copy/paste your best solution to https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors that it flags.  Be sure to include `#!/bin/sh` as the first line. (note the O.P. said he is using `/bin/sh`.) While some encourage leaving an edit trail in postings, I believe the goal of S.O. is to have a simple question and then a simple answer (where appropriate, as it is here IMHO). So I'd recommend that you only include your best solution. again, all IMHO. Good luck and keep reading and posting!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate if I were to add that to make it ```#!/usr/bin/env sh```

Comment: Not all systems support `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, especially the ones that only have `/bin/sh` available. Good luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for all your input, but I am using /bin/sh, and none of the above are working for me, declare not found  , seq not found so still no solution my shell is provided by NuTCRACKER and it is on my works system so I have no choice than to use it.